# How to make an inherited variable private in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

Let's say I have a class MySprite that inherits from Sprite. For a couple of reasons I need to make scaleX in MySprite private. I tried to do this:

```
public class MySprite extends Sprite 
{   
   private var scaleX : Number;
.................
```

Of course it doesn't work and I get the following error:

> 1152: A conflict exists with inherited definition
>   flash.display:DisplayObject.scaleX in namespace public.

So, is there any way to make an inherited variable private in AS3?

Comment: Why would you want to do that in first place?

Comment: I wanted to do this many times in the past. In this case MySprite has a child that uses 9-slice scaling. If I scale the MySprite object, 9-slice scaling doesn't work. Having private scaleX and scaleY would allow me to handle this in the most elegant way. Of course, I could create new variables in MySprite, but there's always a possibility of a coding error where scaleX and scaleY would be changed directly. So, if there's a simple way to make scaleX private, that would be a preferable solution.

Answer (score 1):

you can't do that with an existing class. you'll need to come up with some other way of doing this. You might be able to override the set and get functions, but that might cause other issues.